# Vert.x IO Blocking operation performance

Tags: java, scala, asynchronous, vert.x, event-loop

I'm trying to run a blocking code, like `Thread.sleep(100)` to simulate a heavy database, with a Vert.x 1000 Worker pool size.

```
val options = DeploymentOptions().setWorker(true).setWorkerPoolSize(1000);
vertx.deployVerticle(new DataBase, options)
```

⠀

```
vertx.eventBus().consumer("anAddress").handler((message: Message[String]) => {
  Thread.sleep(100)
  val lines = "teste do joca"
  message.reply(lines)
})
```

But looking at a Jmeter http test, I got only 10.1/sec Throughput.

How could I increase this performance without breaking the eventloop?

Thanks to advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worker verticles handle events on worker threads but a single instance can only handle one event at a given point in time. So you shall deploy as many instances as worker threads if you want to leverage all of them:

```
val options = DeploymentOptions()
  .setWorker(true)
  .setInstances(1000)
  .setWorkerPoolSize(1000);
vertx.deployVerticle(() -> new DataBase(), options);
```

Note that `deploy` here takes a `Supplier` instead of single verticle instance.

Comment: Thanks! Does it has a math calculation to discover instances and poll number? I have now 155/sec Throughput. Still low right?

Comment: There are other factors not related to Vert.x: database connection pool configuration, ... etc. And how you run your benchmark: different machines, datatbase configuration, ... etc. And then of course it depends on you workload.